# Draw rectangles on line of circle on a canvas in android

Tags: android, math, canvas, android-canvas

I'm drawing a circle and I want on the circle line rectangles that are rotated in the right degree. Like on this image:

[image]

With the help off someone on SO I've found a way to do that (almost).

I've got this:

[image]

Like you see there are 2 things missing:

1) they are not on the circle line
2) They are not rotated

I know how to rotate on a canvas in android but then they are all mixed up.

This is my code:

```
    int r = 200;

    canvas.save();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.translate(rect.width() / 2, rect.height() / 2);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, r, mPaint);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    for (int alpha = 0; alpha <= 360; alpha += 20) {

        double x = r/3 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        double y = r/3 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        canvas.translate((float)x, (float)y);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 20, mPaint);

    }
    canvas.restore();
```

Can someone point me out on what I'm doing wrong, why they aren't showing on the line of the circle? And second how to rotate, because when I do canvas.rotate(alpha) they aren't in a circle anymore.

EDIT:

My code is now like this:

```
    int r = 200;

    canvas.save();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.translate(rect.width() / 2, rect.height() / 2);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, r, mPaint);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    for (int alpha = 0; alpha <= 360; alpha += 20) {
        double x = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        double y = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        canvas.rotate(20.f);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 20, mPaint);
    }
    canvas.restore();
```

and it gives me this:

[image]

EDIT 2:

code is like:

```
    int r = 200;

    canvas.save();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.translate(rect.width() / 2, rect.height() / 2);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, r, mPaint);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    for (int alpha = 0; alpha <= 360; alpha += 20) {
        double x = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        double y = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alpha));
        canvas.rotate(20.f);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, -200);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 20, mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
    canvas.restore();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a rotation with a translation sounds like an impossible task. Draw your rectangles straight and rotate the `Canvas` with `Canvas.rotate()` instead.

See:  [Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: change `canvas.translate((float)x, (float)y);` with `canvas.rotate(20.f);`

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I want :-). Can please check my edit. Maybe you see what's the final mistake.

Comment: yeah depends on the size of the rectangles too. Try: `canvas.rotate(20.f); canvas.save(); canvas.translate(0, -200); canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 20, mPaint); canvas.restore();`

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I need. In my edit you can see the screenshot. They lay down. But they must have the right corner like on the first image. Why don't I need to use my calculated x and y? BTW: thanks for your help man!

Comment: `canvas.rotate(20.f); canvas.save(); canvas.translate(0, -200); canvas.drawRect(-10, -35, 10, 35, mPaint); canvas.restore();`. The "-200" is the imaginary circle radius and in this way the center of each rectangle is lying on the circle. Change that if you want a bigger or smaller circle. You can use your variable `r` too, I'm just quickly hacking some code together here

Comment: In your for loop what you call alpha should really be called angle. Then at every 20 degrees you draw a rectangle. If you want more rectangles you can decrease the increment, e.g. `alpha+=10` ... `canvas.rotate(10.f);`. Each rectangle is drawn wrt the origin of a rotated and traslated canvas. Check the docs for drawRect() how to draw a bigger rectangle there